# Extract all substrings between stipulated symbols using regular expressions

Tags: vba

**Excel 2007**

I'd like to extract substrings between symbols "/" from a phrase.

```
Private Function get_all_matches(phrase)
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim result As Variant

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "/.*/"
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set result = regEx.Execute(phrase)
    Set get_all_matches = result
End Function
```

Then I use the function:

```
phrase = "where is /my/ ups /hiding/"
Set keys = get_all_matches(phrase)
```

The result is that keys(0).Value: "/my/ ups /hiding/".

In other words everything between the outer slashes is extracted.
But the expected result is:

```
keys(0).Value: "/my/"
keys(1).Value: "/hiding/"
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\/(.*?)\/` pattern

Pattern explanation:

> **/** matches the character / literally (case sensitive) 1st Capturing
>
> Group **(.*?)*** .? matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> ***?** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) / matches the character /

Test here --> https://regex101.com/r/wdNY18/1